How to call up an anchor program that has a pda using cpi
There was another question here that was similar but it didn't give a code answer. Let's say anchor program A is the one being called and has an initialise function that initialises a pda that it uses to store a u8, as well as a get function that gets the number.
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, random_num: u8) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("Greetings from: {:?}", ctx.program_id);
    msg!("Random number: {}", random_num);
    let random_account = &mut ctx.accounts.random_account;
    random_account.random_number = random_num;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn get_random_num(ctx: Context<GetRandomNum>) -> Result<u8> {
    let random_account = &ctx.accounts.random_account;
    msg!("Random number: {}", random_account.random_number);
    Ok(random_account.random_number)
}


    
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
        #[account(
            init, 
            seeds = [b"random_account", user.key().as_ref()],
            bump,
            payer = user, 
            space = DISCRIMINATOR + RandomNumber::INIT_SPACE
        )]
        pub random_account: Account<'info, RandomNumber>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub user: Signer<'info>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    }
    
        
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct GetRandomNum<'info> {
        #[account(
            seeds = [b"random_account", user.key().as_ref()],
            bump
        )]
        pub random_account: Account<'info, RandomNumber>,
        pub user: Signer<'info>,
    }

How do I call the get random number function using Program B using anchor's cpi tool? It seems I also have to call the initialise function and I get an error stating 'AnchorError caused by account: random_account. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.' as I do not know what accounts to pass in for the pda to be initialised.
This was my attempt:
   pub fn initialize_random_account(
    ctx: Context<InitializeRandomAccount>,
    random_num: u8,
) -> Result<()> {
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.oracle_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_accounts = OracleInitialize {
        random_account: ctx.accounts.random_account.to_account_info(),
        user: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
        system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

    oracle::cpi::initialize(cpi_ctx, random_num)?;

    msg!("Random account initialized with value: {}", random_num);
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeRandomAccount<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"random_account", user.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer=user,
        space = DISCRIMINATOR + RandomNumber::INIT_SPACE,
        owner = oracle::ID // Ensure the account is owned by the oracle program
    )]
    pub random_account: Account<'info, RandomNumber>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub oracle_program: Program<'info, Oracle>,
}

The initialise function is failing so I can't even move on to getting the number.

In the caller function you should take
    /// CHECK: validated in CPI
    pub random_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

Let the program called by CPI validate the seeds, there's no need to validate them twice (nor can you with the anchor decorator, it will expect the program ID of the caller program instead of the one being called by CPI)
For your second question, you probably need your PDA to sign with its seeds, add .with_signer(&[your_seeds]), to the cpi call.
It's common to generate the seeds with a macro to avoid the awkward syntax, for example:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! random_account_signer_seeds {
    ($rand:expr) => {
        &[
            b"random_account",
            $rand.user.as_ref(),
            &[$rand.bump_seed],
        ]
    };
}

(note that I assume you stored bump_seed on the struct as well, which you should to make this more convenient if you don't already). And use it like:
.with_signer(&[random_account_signer_seeds!(your_acc)]),


I saw that it's unsafe to use unchecked accounts, but in this case it's fine since it's not storing funds? (sorry my knowledge on smart contracts is not huge)
Also thank you, I'll try this!

It's not unsafe if you are passing the account to another via CPI, if that second ix you are calling by CPI performs its own validation. You don't have to validate twice. Here your CPI ix already checks the seeds so the top level ix doesn't have to check them again.

I tried to implement what you stated and got it working, but not with having the pda in my oracle, but rather in the caller program. The aspect of the "with signer"and unchecked account was really helpful, thanks!
